# Proving that rational equivalence is an equivalence relation on any set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, rational-numbers

I seek to prove that the rational equivalence relation is an equivalence relation, in that it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

The rational equivalence relation is as follows "Two numbers in a set are rationally equivalent provided their difference is rational".

I know that it is reflexive, since for two points in a set E, a and b, if |a-b| is rational then |b-a| is also rational, because the two are equivalent, and similarly for the irrational case.

I'm not sure how to prove symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: What you proved is the symmetry. For reflexiveness note that $|a-a|=0$ and $0$ is a rational number.

Comment: That would explain my confusion!

Answer (score 2):

Two observations:

1. The absolute value signs are a needless distraction: $|a|$ is rational if and only if $a$ is rational.
2. The transitive property is a consequence of the fact that the sum of two rational numbers is rational.

Comment: How would you show transitivity for the irrationals? it's easy to show that if a-b is rational, and b-c is rational, then a-c is also rational- But how do you show the converse?

Comment: @user3677952: You don't need to show the converse.  Transitivity is a one-way implication.